# labels on tops and bottoms

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

please help me to plot labels on tops and bottoms based on this short indicator [I hope the result will be like this pic lables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyLjR.png).
I tried but it plots labels on all candles not on pivots tops and bottoms only.

```
//@version=5
indicator('piv lbl', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

period   = input.int(200, title="Period")

    
hh = ta.highest(high, period)
ll = ta.lowest(low,   period)

hsrc =  input.source(high , title="High source")
lsrc =  input.source(low  , title="Low  source")

newhh   = high > hh[1]
newll   = low  < ll[1]

hhb = ta.barssince(hh)
plot(hhb)


if hh
    label.new(bar_index, na, yloc=yloc.abovebar) 
if ll
    label.new(bar_index, na, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ta.pivothigh()` and `ta.pivotlow()` functions to find the pivots.

```
//@version=5
indicator("PivotHigh", overlay=true)
leftBars = input(10)
rightBars=input(10)
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)
plotshape(ph, "Pivot High", shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, color.green, -rightBars, "Pivot\nHigh", size=size.small)
plotshape(pl, "Pivot Low", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color.red, -rightBars, "Pivot\nLow", size=size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. But if I used ta.pivothigh or ta.pivotlow with the main code which I need these pivots to feed it unfortunately it will not work . I must use ta.highest and ta.lowest . 
Could you plz fix it with ta.highest and ta.lowest ?